# show button reset when input file have value

Tags: javascript, jquery

i try to create a button reset for input file. everytime input file have value then a button show up to reset the input file. the problem is, i have 6 input file. and when i upload an image on one of the input file, all button show up, even the other input file didnt have value yet. 
how to make specific for the button?

my code like this

```
$("#inputFile1").change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == "")
    $('.reset').css({"display": "none"});
  else
    $('.reset').css({"display": "block"});
})
$("#inputFile2").change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == "")
    $('.reset').css({"display": "none"});
  else
    $('.reset').css({"display": "block"});
})
$("#inputFile3").change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == "")
    $('.reset').css({"display": "none"});
  else
    $('.reset').css({"display": "block"});
})
```

heres jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/30uv0kfa/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I surrounded each group of `input` file and `button` with a `div` and simplified your JS code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".input-file").on("change", function(){
    if($(this).val() == "") {
      $(this).parent().find(".reset").css({"display": "none"});
    } else {
      $(this).parent().find(".reset").css({"display": "block"});
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input class="input-file" id="inputFile1" type="file"/>
  <button class="reset" style="display:none">reset</button>
</div>
<div>
  <input class="input-file" id="inputFile2" type="file"/>
  <button class="reset" style="display:none">reset</button>
</div>
<div>
  <input class="input-file" id="inputFile3" type="file"/>
  <button class="reset" style="display:none">reset</button>
</div>
<div>
  <input class="input-file" id="inputFile4" type="file"/>
  <button class="reset" style="display:none">reset</button>
</div>
<div>
  <input class="input-file" id="inputFile5" type="file"/>
  <button class="reset" style="display:none">reset</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make it like

```
$("#inputFile1,#inputFile2,#inputFile3,#inputFile4,#inputFile5").change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == "")
    $(this).next('.reset').css({"display": "none"});
  else
    $(this).next('.reset').css({"display": "block"});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting individual ids to buttons would do the job. Check this

```
$("#inputFile1").change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == "")
    $('.reset1').css({"display": "none"});
  else
    $('.reset1').css({"display": "block"});
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/30uv0kfa/1/

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way of doing this. I have edited your fiddle
   [JS fiddle URL](https://jsfiddle.net/30uv0kfa/2/)

```
$("input[type='file']").change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == "")
    $(this).next('.reset').css({"display": "none"});
  else
    $(this).next('.reset').css({"display": "block"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use `class`/`attribute` selector instead of `id` to reduce redundancy
- Use [**`.next(SELECTOR)`**](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to select immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements
- Use `toggle(BOOLEAN)` to play with the visibility of the `reset` button instead of `.css` method

```js
$('[type="file"]').change(function() {
  $(this).next('button').toggle(this.value !== '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inputFile1" type="file" />
<button class="reset" style="display:none">reset</button>
<input id="inputFile2" type="file" />
<button class="reset" style="display:none">reset</button>
<input id="inputFile3" type="file" />
<button class="reset" style="display:none">reset</button>
<input id="inputFile4" type="file" />
<button class="reset" style="display:none">reset</button>
<input id="inputFile5" type="file" />
<button class="reset" style="display:none">reset</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use the same `class` for each button, then you can add unique `id` to each button and use it in the script.

```js
$("#inputFile1").change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == "")
    $('#rfile1').css({"display": "none"});
  else
    $('#rfile1').css({"display": "block"});
})
$("#inputFile2").change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == "")
    $('#rfile2').css({"display": "none"});
  else
    $('#rfile2').css({"display": "block"});
})
$("#inputFile3").change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == "")
    $('#rfile3').css({"display": "none"});
  else
    $('#rfile3').css({"display": "block"});
})
$("#inputFile4").change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == "")
    $('#rfile4').css({"display": "none"});
  else
    $('#rfile4').css({"display": "block"});
})
$("#inputFile5").change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == "")
    $('#rfile5').css({"display": "none"});
  else
    $('#rfile5').css({"display": "block"});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inputFile1" type="file"/>
<button class="reset" id="rfile1" style="display:none">reset</button>
<input id="inputFile2"  type="file"/>
<button class="reset" id="rfile2" style="display:none">reset</button>
<input id="inputFile3" type="file"/>
<button class="reset" id="rfile3" style="display:none">reset</button>
<input id="inputFile4" type="file"/>
<button class="reset" id="rfile4" style="display:none">reset</button>
<input id="inputFile5" type="file"/>
<button class="reset" id="rfile5" style="display:none">reset</button>
```

The other way without add unique id to each button is create a general `change` event for `input[type='file']`:

```
$("input[type='file']").change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == "")
    $(this).next('.reset').css({"display": "none"});
  else
    $(this).next('.reset').css({"display": "block"});
});
```